# How many simultaneous connections can be made to a Firebird database server running on Windows XP Pro?

Tags: tcp, windows-xp, firebird, database-server

I have Firebird version 2.1 running as a database server on a Windows XP Pro machine.

There are 35 users on my network all using the same FB server. Though not all of them may connect simultaneously I'm pretty sure at least 20 do.

Why is this possible if there is a 10 session limit on Windows XP Pro?

Does this post [RE : [ib-support] Hosting Firebird on XP Pro (was Re: Windows XP Home)](http://fb-list-archive.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/firebird-support/2003/2/21405.html) have it right?

I'd like more details to understand what is going on here?

Comment: In Firebird 2.1+ you can select * from mon$attachments to see who is connected.

Comment: There is - AFAIK - no 10 session limit on Windows XP Pro, but there is a 10 **half-open** connection limit (although I believe they removed that in later versions or servicepacks), which means that on a non-server Windows there can be only 10 connections where the TCP/IP handshake hasn't been completed yet. There however is no (or at least a higher) connection limit for established connections.